# After rotate 4 time my scrollview is work

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

M new in iOS, and I learn objective c language.
here I try to work with scrollview and screen rotation, below code is post, when run application that time scrollview can't display or work but after four time rotate scrollview is work.
so please help me.
Thank You.

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        //Landscape
        /*self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 728);
        self.view.hidden = NO;*/
        //self.scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 728);
        [_scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(736, 1000)];

    } else {
        //self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 414, 800);
        [_scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(414 , 1200)];
        //self.View.hidden=NO;
        //self.view.hidden=YES;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Will you please set Scrollview contentSize in ViewDidLoad method.

Comment: If scrollview is not scrolling there may be error like scrollview content size is not greater than scroolview size or if you are using constraint on scrollview it is not set properly.  If you are creating scrollview in xib first create UIView as a subview of UIScrollView to make its contentView.

Comment: Hey, scrollView is scrolling but you rotate 4 time right, left, upper, lower then after scrollView is work.